# node.js USB (hid) Barcode Scanner read Buffer

Tags: node.js, usb, buffer, barcode-scanner, hid

i'm using node.js, to read data from a Barcode Scanner. So that is my code:

```
var HID = require('node-hid');
var usb = require('usb');

// Honeywell Scanner
var vid = 0xc2e;
var pid = 0xbe1;

var d = new HID.HID(vid, pid);

d.on("data", function (data) {

console.log(data);

});
d.on("error", function (error) {
console.log(error);
d.close();
});
```

My Problem is, that i  get a Buffer  that looks like < Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 >. After scanning a barcode (for example a barcode with the id 12) the console returns something like that

```
<Buffer 00 00 53 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 53 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 1e 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 00 00 1f 00 00 00 00 00>
```

How can i convert this Buffer output into a readable string? In that case it would be a 12.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want to do is to decode your `data` buffer.

**To decode a buffer**, you simply use the built-in [.toString()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) method, passing in the character encoding to decode to:

```
data.toString('hex'); //<-- Decodes to hexadecimal
data.toString('base64'); //<-- Decodes to base64
```

If you don't pass anything to `toString`, **utf8** will be the default.

---

**EDIT**

If you'd like to know which character encodings are currently supported by Node (other than **hex**, **[base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5)** and **utf8**), visit the [official docs.](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings)

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia great tip! should be marked as the answer.. Quick question, when console logging data.toString() I get random squares along with the value of the barcode e.g 1234 Any idea what this is?

Comment: @Dev.W Did you resolve your issue of getting random squares along with the value of the barcode?